# Ajax not working in IE for form post

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a form that performs dynamic calculations and posts to Pardot simultaneously.  The ajax code works in all browsers except IE.  Is there any reason it won't work in IE?  Here is the code:

```
$('#greenQuote').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    premium();

    var theData = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('http://go.mysite.com/l/34381/2014-05-19/hr8w', theData).success(function(data){
    });
});
```

I have also added the following code and tested after viewing responses to other similar questions, but have had no luck.  It was placed above the "$.post."

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false})
```

Comment: What error is being thrown in IE?

Comment: what version of jquery and IE?

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything except your ajax ($.post) call? Does it work then?

Comment: @dragonslovetacos - then the form would be submitted normally (without ajax) and you'd probably also get an undefined variable error for 'theData'.

Comment: @Joe - I don't see an error in Developer Tools.

Comment: @ps2goat - IE Version 9.  jQuery v1.11.1.

Comment: @user3524193 - have you used IE 9's developers tools to see what the response is to the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following edits were made to the original code.  I have also added an additional script to my page. This code is hosted by CDNJS and can be found at:  http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.2/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js.

```
$('#greenQuote').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    premium();
    var theData = $(this).serialize();

    //Eliminates "No Transport" Error in ie
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

    if('withCredentials' in new XMLHttpRequest())
    {
        //alert("CORS supported (XHR)");
        $.post('http://go.mysite.com/l/34381/2014-05-19/hr8w', theData);
    }
    else if(typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined")
    {
        //alert("CORS supported (XDR)");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://go.mysite.com/l/34381/2014-05-19/hr8w',
            data: theData,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Not an answer, but wanted to elaborate on my comment.
What happens if you do this...

```
$('#greenQuote').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('http://go.mysite.com/l/34381/2014-05-19/hr8w', $(this).serialize()).success(function(data){
console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I only ask, is if the JS is not getting to your ajax request, there might be something in your `premium()` method that is causing the system to give up.

Comment: No luck. Still the same thing and no errors are showing up in ie dev tools.

Comment: I removed the premium() function and it still did not work.  It is definitely processing the entire code, as I placed a success alert at the very end of the code and received it upon submitting the form.  Also, there are no errors in ie developers tools.  I'm not sure where to go from here.